# How do I effectivly an profitably, make a career out of independent freelancing?

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms, communication, working-from-home, clients

I've been researching a lot about freelancing, an to my surprise, I'm a little interested in becoming an independent freelancer! In accordance I am inquiring on how to become a successful freelancer that actually makes a profit, an is actually worthwhile?

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on your personal circumstances and the business domain in which you want to offer your services.

- Do you have sufficient experience for someone to hire you?
- Can you find and keep clients?
- Are clients in that business segment used to outsourcing work?
- Do you have a sufficient financial buffer?
- Local laws, regulations and taxation may also need to be considered

Answer (score 0):

Freelancing as?  I was in a similar circumstance.  It depends on what industry you are offering services in, but you might find it helpful to consider yourself as a "consultant."
(Such as) If you are freelancing as a writer/copywriter- create a website or freelance website profile page as an actual business/agency instead of titling yourself "Freelancer."
I am in a mix of Healthcare and Legal and I.t. world- so, it was better to market myself as a Legal/Medical Consultant and then list the services I offer as such...  Just an idea.  Look into making a CV or PowerPoint Pres (link) that's publicly available, helps boost legitimate points when businesses are evaluating your professional presence.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a skill or ability others would *want* to utilize
2. Advertise/market your ability/skill to get others hopefully contacting you
3. Seek out customers and "sell" them on your skill/ability
4. Fulfill projects successfully leaving happy customers who hopefully
   pass on your name to others seeking the same skils/abilities
5. Repeat